# What were the Dementors doing to Harry and what exactly is the "Dementor's Kiss"?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-prisoner-of-azkaban

If Dementors are controlled by the ministery and looking for prisoners, why did they do that to Harry in the train in *Harry Potter and The Prisoner of Azkaban*? Is that their expedient effect? (When they accept Dementors to search the students train it means it shouldn’t be harmful or fatal! Wasn’t it?)

Was the thing they did to Harry the Dementor's kiss or is it just the thing they did to Sirius Black? When do they use the Dementor's kiss?

Is their effect permanent or is it just for the time they are around?

(I read Pottermore but I didn't get my answers. [This link](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dementor) can be useful but because English is not my language it was hard for me to read it.)

Answer (score 1):

During Prisoner of Azkaban, the Dementors were supposed to guard Hogwarts Grounds against Sirius Black. Evidently, they went to the trouble of checking the train which was occupied by Harry, and they thought he was Sirius Black.

Enough time and Dementors would make you mentally damaged and/or take away your soul via the Kiss. However, Remus Lupin was there to prevent from the Dementor doing further harm to Harry. As long as they are around, it will turn very cold and make the surroundings feel very horrid.

Comment: Why did they think Harry was Sirius Black? I forgot that point.

Comment: @Taladris As told afterwards, Sirius was Harry's Godfather and there was quite a resemblance between the two wizards. His appearance and heritage might have played a hand in the Dementors boarding the train

Comment: I agree with the answer of the duplicate question, they "sensed tasty food" in Harry.

Comment: My question is not a “duplicate”! Because it’s different. I wanted to know more about dementors effect and kiss than the train scene. Thanks